# Is it possible to invoke .NET Reflector when pressing F1 in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, reflector

When I press F1 in Visual Studio 2008, I would like to start .NET reflector and navigate to the selected class/method (instead of waiting for the Visual Studio documentation to start up).

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio in that way?

---

Follow-up question:

- how to determine the type/assembly under the caret (as described in [x0n's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858089/is-it-possible-to-invoke-net-reflector-when-pressing-f1-in-visual-studio/858129#858129))?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely.

You would have to write a Macro (Tools > Macros) to find the context Assembly & Type under the caret, then spawn:

```
Reflector <assemblyname> /select:my.namespace.typename
```

And finally rebind F1 to your Macro (although I would be inclined to bind it to a variant, like ctrl+shift+f1 or something since you don't always hit f1 for type help)

-Oisin

Answer (score 0):

This is not precisely an answer to your question, but I would like to add the fact that there is also a built-in way in Visual Studio to open the (de-compiled) source code of the definition of the currently selected class/method by simply pressing `F12`.